# CSS Variable loading svg file multiple times

Tags: css, angular, sass

I am using variables in CSS/SCSS. I want to set a background (using an SVG file), but it is re-loading every time I navigate or perform some other action.

[image: Please see the image attached]

My -Variables.scss file:

```
:root {
  --backgroundTheme: url('triangle-dark.svg') no-repeat;
}
$variables: (
  --backgroundTheme: var(--backgroundTheme)
);
```

My styles.scss file:

```
@import "~assets/_variable";

body:before {
  background-size: cover;
  background: var(--backgroundTheme);
}
```

How can I avoid multiple times loading of this file?

PS: This is an Angular 8 project.

Comment: Seeing a similar issue only on specific devices.  Ever solve this?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem recently. It was caused by the inspector - "Disable cache" was enabled:
[image]

You just need to uncheck it and it will stop making new requests.

Answer (score 0):

To use the image multiple times in the DOM with only one request from the CSS you should use the `content` property of your pseudo element target to render the image:

```
body::before {
  content: var(--backgroundTheme, 'alt text');
}
```

Although you'll probably need another approach in handling the image. It might not work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have two possible idea, not sure if they works for you but it's an easy check:

- If you can, don't use css variables, use scss instead. My general approach is to have a `settings.scss` file and import it whenever needed in the other files. It's a personal preference, I find it easier to manage like that.
- It could as well be something wrong in the backend, are the caching headers set right? You can check that in Chrome itself, by clicking on *tringle-dark.svg*, *Headers* tab, then *Response Headers*.